# Display text value instead of number in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in which my datas are displayed. In my database table the branches are to be represented in numbers like 1,2,3 etc. So after displaying in crystal report the place of branch name shows as 1. So instead of number I need to show it as office.
example: If the branch name is '1' then in crystal report it will display as 'office', how can I achieve this?

Comment: are these numbers and description are mapped in database table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
StringYourVar text := Totext({YourNumberField} , 6 , "YourText");
```

or [this](http://kenhamady.com/formulas/form15.shtml).

Comment: I dont want to change num to string instead if my branchcode is 1 then display in crystal report as office and branchcode is 2 then display as store

Comment: OK, I understand. Right click on the field (in the CR preview) and you have "Display string" or "To Text String". On the right side you have the formula button... There make a IF statement according to your requirment... So IF(myfield == "1") then myfield = 'Office'. This is a pseudo code, but I hope you will understand. Give a feedback if you succeded.

Comment: I have added this, but it shows error  IF({inv.BranchCode} == "1") then {inv.BranchCode} = 'Office'

Comment: Well, I gave you pseudo code... Just google a bit about it. My problem was that I was getting flag from DB: 0,1,2 and according to the number, I need to make a string preview and it worked with IF ELSE statement. @vishnusuresh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe This situation ([Display keywords instead of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215244/display-keywords-instead-of-integers)) can help you.
`If {YourNumberField} = 1 Then "Office" 
Esle If {YourNumberField} = 2 Then "YourText"` .
make sure use crystal syntax in editor