# Display keywords instead of integers

Tags: crystal-reports

My table returns 1, 2, or 3 for my field. How can I change this in my report to display "active", "inactive", and "lost" respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a formula named `@TagName` for example. It contains the following code:

```
IF {Tag} = 1 Then
  "Active"
Else IF {Tag} = 2 Then
  "Inactive"
ELSE IF {Tag} = 3 Then
  "Lost"
ELSE
  ""
```

Then use the `@TagName` field instead of `Tag`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i'm following your code but it give me an error " A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time , date-time, or string is expected here" and it highlight at "IF" statement.

Comment: What is the type of your field tag? number or string?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't copy my code 100%... for example instead of {Tag} you should double click your field to take its exact name!!

Comment: my field type is (int)my code look like : IF {Tag.Status} = 0  Then  "inActive"
Else IF {Tag.Status} = 1 Then "Active"  ...

Comment: my problem look same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126253/display-text-value-instead-of-number-in-crystal-report?rq=1) but i find no solution to my case work

Comment: and your {Tag.Status} is coming from  a proceudre? a view? a table?

Comment: i make a viewmodel in project and use that to construct my report. i don't want to use  procedure because it may cause reduce performance

Comment: sorry i'm not familiar with ViewModels, but it seems that you are choosing your field wrong...